# Backbone.js Collection.sync & spring endpoints

Tags: json, spring, backbone.js, jackson

I have a backbone.js client app and Spring on the app tier. In Backbone I'm using a Collection of 'ServerConfig' objects... the URL of the backbone collection points to a spring endpoint.

The 'GET' request returns an ArrayList of a POJO called 'ServerRuntimeConfig' which ultimately ends up returning a JSON response with the following response body:

```
[{"useIUX":true,"serverDomainName":"localhost","selected":true}]
```

The 'PUT' request, which is called when I do a 'sync' on the collection sends the following JSON request with the below request body (same as the GET):

```
[{"useIUX":true,"serverDomainName":"localhost","selected":true}]
```

The problem is that I can't get spring to automatically map the JSON collection into a collection of POJOs on the PUT... so I've had to do it manually.

Here is the GET end point

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/runtimeConfigs", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> handleConfigRequest(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    // first grab all of the hostnames from the properties file
    ArrayList<String> allServersDomains = new ArrayList();
    List<String> servers = Arrays.asList(
        StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(
            this.getAppProperties().get("serverList"), ","));
    allServersDomains.addAll(servers);
    MyTTJMXClient jmxClient = new MyTTJMXClient();
    return jmxClient.readRemoteConfigurations(allServersDomains);

}
```

Here is the PUT endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/runtimeConfigs", 
                method = RequestMethod.PUT,
                consumes = "application/json", 
                produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> handleConfigUpdate(
        @RequestBody String body, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String jsonSource = body;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> serverConfigs = new ArrayList();
    try {
        serverConfigs = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, 
               new TypeReference<ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig>>() { } );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MyTTJMXClient jmxClient;
    jmxClient = new MyTTJMXClient();
    return jmxClient.setRemoteConfigurations(serverConfigs);

}
```

Is there a way to avoid the manual Jackson mapping I'm doing in the PUT endpoint? I tried the following endpoint signature but serverConfigs is always null

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/runtimeConfigs", 
                method = RequestMethod.PUT,
                consumes = "application/json", 
                produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> handleConfigUpdate(
       ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> serverConfigs, 
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Again, the manual Jackson mapping does the trick, but it's not using the awesomeness that is Spring.

Has anyone else out there built a Spring end point that automatically maps Backbone/JSON collections to POJOs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the mapping you've used in your PUT method works,
Try to change your method signature from:

```
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> handleConfigUpdate(
       ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> serverConfigs, 
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response) {
```

to:

```
@ResponseBody
public ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> handleConfigUpdate(
       @RequestBody ArrayList<ServerRuntimeConfig> serverConfigs, 
       HttpServletRequest request, 
       HttpServletResponse response) {
```

The `@RequestBody` annotation is the important part here. It will automatically use spring's  converter (in this case, jackson) to populate the variable.